# How do I combine a standalone c application into a c++ one?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker

I was working on a C++ app (call it `recorder.cpp`) that includes some C++ libraries from elsewhere (which have to use c++14, so I am stuck on that front).  Currently my app is working, but it is just doing configuration based off of the external libraries and command line arguments.

There is a separate C app (call it `receiver.c`) that works independently that I basically want to combine with `recorder`.  I think the easy way would be to copy and paste all of `receiver` into `recorder`, but that seems a bit redundant (not to mention if I make mods to `receiver` in the future, I will need to then make the same changes in `recorder`).  So I was trying to figure out if there is a way to link them so that I can call `receiver` from the `recorder` app.  I know that I can't just call `receiver`'s main(), but I wasn't sure if there was a way to build `receiver` so that it acts more like a library yet still can be built as its standalone app.

Comment: Most operating systems have ways of executing arbitrary programs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I believe the question is more about including `C` source in `c++` code, not running a compiled executable.

Comment: @ryyker Yes the text inside the main body seems to indicate it, which then seems conflicts with the title.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Yeah, I guess I wasn't very clear.  I would think that the more elegant solution would be the "linking" version, but maybe the direct call is the way to go. I need to research ryyker's answer some more.

Comment: If linking `receiver` and `recorder` into a single executable, note that you can't have two `main` functions in the same executable, so you will have to work around that somehow if you need to call `receiver`'s `main` function from `recorder`, for example by renaming `receiver`'s `main` function using a preprocessor macro.

Comment: Since you are really talking source code, have you considered just removing the main() function and including the rest of the `C` code as part of the `C++ compile?

Comment: @ryyker After playing with this some, reading on the net and all the comments/answer (and my unclear issue), I think that this might be the easiest approach. I guess we should probably close the question. Thanks to all though.

Answer (score 1):

*"...I was trying to figure out if there is a way to link them so that I can call receiver from the recorder app."*

Yes - But the simpler, more direct way is to copy the `reciever.c` code (minus its `main()` function) in with the C++ code. This would require that there is no syntax in the `C` code that would violate `C++` rules. (eg. casting the return of `malloc()` for example is required in C++, but is not recommended in C.)  But because most C syntax is completely `C++` compatible, there should be little or no modifications necessary.  Now all your code is together, and can be simply compiled as `C++`.

The linking approach however, would require compiling all of the functions of your *stand-alone* program (again, leaving out the `main()` function into a library.  eg a DLL or shared library.  That library can be linked using  `extern "C" { ... } within the`C++ header file to surround the `C` function prototypes that are defined in the `C` library file. Those functions in the surround will be compiled with `C` linkage rather than `C++`.  A brief example:

```
    // C++ code
    extern "C" void f(int); // one way
    extern "C" {    // another way
        int g(double);
        double h();
    };
    void code(int i, double d)
    {
        f(i);
        int ii = g(d);
        double dd = h();
        // ...
    }
```

[Reproduced from here...](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#overview-mixing-langs)

Note, included in link is this statement: *"...In addition, you’ll need to read the rest of this section to find out how to make your C functions callable by C++ and/or your C++ functions callable by C."*

*EDIT* to add information from comments:
Regarding creating a library.  The library could then be used by both programs and not maintained in two places. This would complicate versioning and there could be future issues if the 2 programs diverge in the future. Also note that using a static rather than shared library is also possible. These approaches have different versioning implications as future changes happen.  (from @Avi Berger)

...Or, if your intent is to have a common *.c file so changes made for one app are easily included in the other, you don't make a library but simply link in the .o file.  (from @Goswin von Brederlow)

Comment: But that is for calling a function, not the whole application right?

Comment: @ryyker You can, but it doesn't compile the code as C it compiles it as C++, which might make a difference. Only the function signatures are "C" style.

Comment: Better to compile the C code as a separate source module. Most C++ IDEs and makefiles should allow this. Then use `extern "C"` to get access to the C functions from the C++. If that is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @GemTaylor - If that is what is needed, yes.  But text in OP seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @toozie21 - _But that is for calling a function,_ Yes, when using `extern "C" { ... }`, it will include what ever function declarations included in the curly braces.  So anything inside will be declared some to be of "C" linkage, rather than "C++"

Comment: @ryyker OK, but I think I am missing something. I had skimmed through your link before I posted that comment because it still didn't seem to cover the scenario. I realize that I seem to be unintentionally asking un-clear questions. I understand what you are describing, but if I do ```extern "C" {int main(int argc, char *argv)};```, I unclear how ```recorder``` will know the difference between its out main() and ```receiver```'s <<edit>> I wrote this the same time as Ian's comment in my original question, his comment is exactly my concern.

Comment: @toozie21- Please see edits to clarify .  Sorry for the unclear language.  Keep in mind the most common way this is used is to surround library function decalrations in a `C++` header file that you what to compile with `C` linkage rather than `C++`.

Comment: You might explicitly note that the library could then be used by both programs and not maintained in two places. This would complicate versioning and there could be future issues if the 2 programs diverge in the future. Also note that using a static rather than shared library is also possible. These approaches have different versioning implications as future changes happen.

Comment: Or you don't make a library but simply link in the .o file. I think the OPs main point was to have a common *.c file so changes made for one app are easily included in the other.

Comment: @AviBerger - That is a good point, I have quoted you in the answer.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - Also a good point, have quoted you in the answer.

Comment: Another note. The C app should probably provide a .h file. And you can't have `extern "C" {}` in C code. The .h file should use `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - generally I would expect that the `C` function prototypes needed would be added (copied from the original) to the C++ header, surrounded with the `extern "C"` modification.  That is how I have always done it.  This is simpler.  There are many variations possible.  The basic question _can it be done_ has been answered sufficiently. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile the object files `recorder.o` and `receiver.o` in the usual way.  Make sure they don't both have a `main()` function: either `#ifdef` it out conditionally, or (better) compile it in its own object file for each program (e.g. `recorder_main.cpp` and `receiver_main.c`).

With this latter approach, the Makefile is quite simple, as we can let Make use its built-in rules to make the object files correctly.  All we have to do is tell it how to link:

```make
receiver: receiver_main.o receiver.o
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

recorder: recorder_main.o recorder.o receiver.o
        $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Notice that we need to link `recorder` with the C++ linker (that understands name mangling) rather than the C linker.

If you want separate source directories, that's easily managed using a `VPATH` in the Makefile.